# Why my added libraries are automatically removed from "Java Build Path" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am working on a Web Application;
I added  libraries to my project via "Java Build Path"
Application is running perfectly but when I made changes to my  .jsp  file and  refreshed the the page on Browser;
the added libraries automatically removed.
Now how can  fix it??? 
i am using apache-tomcat-7.0.37.
as every time I update my .jsp file or make any other changes I need to add the libraries again.
Any advice or suggestion would be highly appreciable. Thank you!

Comment: Which libraries? Which version of Eclipse? What's providing the support for developing web applications? Did you add anything else?

Comment: I am using  Indigo Service Release 1. 
I just added the required libraries:  
ear, web App Libraries and an external jar: servlet-api .  
I didn't add anything else considerable enough to mention..

Comment: 1) UPGRADE TO THE CURRENT VERSION.
2) You shouldn't need to manually add the servlet-api jar; those APIs should be part of the Java Build Path once you target your Tomcat runtime (Tomcat supplies it because Tomcat itself needs them to run).

Comment: Actually, the same application is running on my other PC with the same version perfectly; don't need to add the libraries again and again but something is wrong with the settings of the IDE in my office PC; and I could not figure it out.